# Cómo hacer que un form que hace funcion de modal, evite cerrarse cuando presiono ciertas teclas

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo un inconveniente.

Estoy llamando un `Form` hijo que hace la función de un modal.

Cuando lo llamo y presiono las teclas `Enter` y `Esc` se me cierra el `Form` hijo, pero quisiera evitar que pase eso.

Estoy utilizando el evento `Closing`,  pero necesito obtener el `Keycode` para hacer las condiciones, pero no puedo porque no me brinda esas opciones en ese evento.

```
private void modalEntrada_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e){
    //e.KeyCode y e.KeyChar me generan error por que no lo "encuentra"        
   e.Cancel = true;            
}
```

Entonces es en ese eveneto donde quisiera hacer las condiciones para cuando presiono las teclas mencionadas evitar se cierre.

Si conocen otra forma que incluso sea simple lo agradeceria.

PD: el `modal` lo ejecuto con `ShowDialog();`

Comment: No entiendo que las teclas Enter o Esc originen ese comportamiento, tal vez tenga que ver con lo que tienes en el propio form. Si quieres procesar las teclas hay un par eventos del formulario para ello.

Comment: ¿Es posible que tengas definido en el formulario las propiedades AcceptButton y CancelButton? Al pulsar la tecla Enter es como pinchar el AcceptButton y pulsar la tecla Esc es como pinchar el CancelButton. Eso explicaría ese comportamiento. Si les quitas esas propiedades ya no lo haría.

Comment: @bsebe, solucione el error, el tabindex hacia Focus al btn de cerrar entonces al hacer ese Enter pasaba eso de cerrarse.

Comment: Gracias igual por los mensajes. Soy nuevo aún en este lenguaje.

Comment: @DAD Genial que encontrases el problema. Por favor, si puedes, pon una respuesta con la solución y aceptala para que si alguien tiene el mismo problema pueda verla.